# SQL Server BIGINT or DECIMAL(18,0) for primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005, types

We have a SQL Server 2005 database for which we want to improve performance of bulk delete/insert/selects and I notice it uses `decimal(18,0)` for its primary keys. I understand this will give us many more values than `bigint` but was hoping it might be a quick win and should last us for many million years of growth by my calculations.

I see in the .net [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) decimals take 16 bytes instead of the 8 required by longs but in SQL Server it looks like `bigint` [take 8 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) but the `decimal(18,0)` takes only [5 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) - as also seen by `select DATALENGTH(max(id)) from table`. Is this correct?

Is there any other reason `bigint` might be slower or should I stick to `decimal(18,0)`?

Comment: in your case decimal(18,0) takes 9 bytes not 5

Comment: The DATALENGTH function says 5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DATALENGTH is casting to varchar before counting bytes. So your max value is < 100000.

The 9 bytes can be proved with this. [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) has a max_length column (decimal is fixed length so it is always 9 bytes, before you ask otherwise)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo (bar decimal(18,0))
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('foo') 
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.foo
GO
```

For legacy reasons, `decimal(18, 0)` was often used as a surrogate for "64 bit integer" before bigint was added with SQL Server 2000.

`decimal(18, 0)` and `bigint` are roughly the same in range: decimal is one byte more at 9 bytes *as per the documentation*

On top of that, plain integer will be fractionally (maybe not measurable) faster then decimal. Saying that, if expect to have more then 4 billion rows in the next year or 5, then the performance should matter. If it doesn't, then just use `int`

Comment: A bigint fits into a single register on a 64-bit machine, a 9-byte decimal does not. If we're talking about a primary key that is used all over the place I would expect this to be quite costly.

Answer (score 22):

**You get this range with bigint:**

```
-2^63 to 2^63-1 

also known as roughly:

-9.2 x 10^18 to 9.2 x 10^18
```

**You get this range with decimal(18,0)**:

```
-10^18 to 10^18
```

**Decimal: Storage Bytes per Precision**

```
Precision    Storage Bytes
1-9:         5
10-19:       9
20-28:       13
29-38:       17
```

**Integer Types and Storage Bytes**

```
integer type    Storage Bytes
bigint          8
int             4
smallint        2
tinyint         1
```

**Thoughts**

The two examples posted in your Question actually yield virtually the same quantity of unique values.

Also, you are not going to see a significant performance change no matter your choice, but you will see a change in efficiency for other programmers on the team if you start using decimals where programmers are expecting an integer. This is a minor point.

To address your specific issue, if you want a larger range, use Decimal(38,0). This gives you:

```
-10^38 to 10^38
```

If you are concerned about speed, use the minimum precision that will last the lifetime of your software.

If you're not measuring time in nano-seconds, then choose the option that will fit best for your programmers' mindsets and your desire to have a very long set of numbers.

**References**

- [Decimal and Numeric Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)
- [Integer Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

Comment: I guess "roughly" is a relative term here because `bigint` is over nine times bigger than `decimal(18,0)` eg `9,223,372,036,854,775,807 / 999,999,999,999,999,999`, and over 92% the size of a `decimal(19,0)`; however I guess it's over four billion times closer to `bigint` than just `int` is...

Comment: @Gregory The "roughly" is in regards to the rounding to "9.2" for ease of reading