# MS Access 2016, VBA: How do I update/refresh Textbox controls that display #Deleted after deleting a record without pressing F5?

Tags: ms-access, vba

On my form, bound to a temp table, I have 3 bound textbox controls and 3 unbound textbox controls. I add the 3 missing pieces of information in the unbound textboxes and save the values of all 6 textboxes to a permanent table. Next I run a delete query from a command button to remove the record from the temp table. After the query finishes (in the blink of an eye) all 3 bound controls still display the deleted data. If I continue from this point I get an error message from a bound combo box that says the table is in use by another user AND the 3 bound textboxes now display #Deleted. Even the navigation buttons still show the original number of records UNTIL I press F5. Then I am good to go again.

In my research I have tried Me.ReQuery, Me.ReFresh, Me.RePaint and Sendkeys {F5} in the Form_AfterUpDate event. Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660392/rows-showing-as-deleted). If none of these work, consider to show us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still on the no-longer existing record, so you will need to move to another record. I am not sure if you require the new record (`acNewRec`), so I have put next record:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
```