# ms-access 2016 from ms-office 365 does not link successfully to ms-sql-server developer edition on the same laptop

Tags: ms-access

access 2016 that i have as part of my ms-office 365 subscription, it does not successfully link to my sql server developer edition 2017 database! What i mean is that

- the linking process goes through
- but when i open a table, only the delete marks show
- And what more: if i click on the first record of the table, the entire record shows, but no other record shows. Only #deleted# marks show up
- the records are ok in sql server, i checked that in ms-visual(MS-VS) studio and also in management studio(SMSS).
- both SMSS AND MS-VS are in use with me !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rows showing as #DELETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660392/rows-showing-as-deleted)

Comment: hey, but the same records show up correctly in MS-VS and in SMSS! Why ?

Comment: Did you read the linked Q+A? If you don't have BigInt or similar PKs, read https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+sql+%22%23deleted%22