# Latest MS Access Build 2205 breaks PostgreSQL ODBC Drivers?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2016

Hoping to verify this with someone else before I go to far down the rabbit hole.

I got a new laptop today and have been setting it up.  As part of that I installed the PostgreSQL ODBC drivers and connected to a couple of tables in an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance, and immediately got the all fields / all rows showing as #deleted error that has been noted at various times.

I had the new machine side-by-side with my old machine (which still linked to the same tables happily), and I've been using the same config for a couple of years now, so I'm confident it isn't a mismatched field type in an index or some of the historical issues that appear to have causes this type of behavior.

I stepped the PostgreSQL ODBC drivers down from the latest (13.02) version incrementally until I got to the version working on my old machine (11.0) with no improvement.

At this point I compared the MS Access versions and determined that my new machine was running Build 2205 and the old (working) machine was running 2204.  I ran the MS Office update on the older machine, getting Build 2205, and immediately had the same behavior i.e. all linked tables open with all rows/fields showing as #Deleted :(

Hoping someone else out there can confirm / verify the same behavior, and or had a workaround?

Cheers!

Comment: Sounds very much like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72431994/delete-viewing-sql-server-table-in-access , I hadn't read yet that it also affects a PostgreSQL backend.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out, the article is reporting a similar problem, but it links to a much for definitive report here.  Bug introduced with the 2205 build  https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=msaccess-bug-v2205-odbc-deleted-nvarchar-primary-key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#DELETE viewing SQL Server table in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72431994/delete-viewing-sql-server-table-in-access)