# Linked tables in MS Access showing #Deleted in all rows and columns

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, office365, linked-tables

I ran into an issue today where MS Access version 2022 (Build 14931.20392) started just showing "#Deleted" for all rows and columns in a linked table to a SQL Server 2012 database.

No changes were done on the database server. We are not sure when the user's copy of MS Access was updated but we do know it is running version 2022.

- Permissions were good.
- A user DNS to the SQL Server was used to connect using the "SQL Server" driver.
- I switched to the "SQL Native Client 11" driver, relinked the tables, and got the same error.
- I had the user relink the tables in Access as well as refresh with no help.
- I could not recreate this same issue with the same Access database running Access version 2018.

Comment: In that case, post you Q&A as a **Q&A** i.e. post a question and then add your own answer as an actual answer! Otherwise it will get lost and closed.

Comment: And it looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72431994/delete-viewing-sql-server-table-in-access) anyway.

Comment: This happens when you have an open linked table (open in Dataview or on a bound form); and your database connection (networking) is interrupted. Just restarting your application (form/datesheet view etc) should resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The FIX!! We were able to fix the issue by installing "Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" and recreating the ODBC DSN used by access to connect to the SQL server. Once the DNS was created, the tables were relinked and worked.

This for sure fixed our issue and worked on several other workstations. I am just posting this here because I had not found any helpful information on this issue. I just hope to help the next person running into this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, and was recent fixed.

The workaround (in most cases) was to dump the legacy sql driver, and adopt a native driver (such as noted above native 17).

From what I know, depending on your update stream (from office 365), the fix has been deployed as I write this. However, for some, the last week did cause trouble for some.

Answer (score 0):

Fix..  For my "delete" issues.  With Link Manager I relinked all the tables for SQL SERVER through ODBC 11 in my MS Access frontend app.  This corrected my problem