# Arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting:

> Msg 8115 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int error

For this  query:

```
DECLARE @x  int     
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Y)     
  BEGIN          
    SET @x = (SELECT max(Id )  from Y)+1    
  END    
ELSE 
  BEGIN         
    SET @x = 1   
  END
```

I tried to cast Id to Big int and I also tried by changing x as Big int, but still getting same error.

Comment: Can you try `declare @x bigint`

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: I tried with @x bigint but no use

Comment: @aks Did you try using the IDENTITY(1,1) for auto increment of ID column?

Comment: Is there possibility the `max(Id)` is the maximum value for the `bigint` type?

Comment: Can you show us your table structure?

Comment: In the table structure ID is decimal datatype

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code nothing is wrong with it, please refer this [LINK](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/06/sql-server-fix-error-msg-8115-level-16-state-2-line-2-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type/) it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ranges of values that can be stored within the types:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(v=SQL.90).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

(and also check this: [SQL Server BIGINT or DECIMAL(18,0) for primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838374/sql-server-bigint-or-decimal18-0-for-primary-key))

The `ID` column of the `decimal` type may cause problem in your case.